# Why is my Parallel Sum slower than Sum() in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

**Post Updated with some profiling details below**

Why is the my code (Function p(sum,array) ) demonstrated below, slower than a serial sum()? What I do in this function is break up the array into 6 smaller parts and sum those in parallel. But It seems that sum() alone is faster than this approach... why?

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process
from timeit import default_timer as timer
the_remainder = 0
ok = False

def chunks(l, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from l."""
    for i in xrange(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]

def a(arr, q, b):
    q.append(b(arr))



def p(b,arr, a='a',debug=False,cores=7):
    global the_remainder
    global ok
    length = len(arr)
    if length == 1:
        return arr[0]
    manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
    q = manager.list()

    list_of_processes = []

    if length % 2 == 1:
        the_remainder = arr.pop()
        ok = True

    if debug:
        print arr




    parts = []

    # How many parts do you want ?
    if length / (cores-1) == 1 or length / (cores-1)  == 0:
        parts = list(chunks(arr, 2))
    else:
        parts = list(chunks(arr, length / (cores-1)))

    if debug:
        print parts


    for i in parts:
        list_of_processes.append(Process(target=eval(a, globals()), args=(i, q, b)))
        list_of_processes[-1].start()

    for i in list_of_processes:
        i.join()

    if ok:
        q.append(the_remainder)
        ok = False

    return p(b,q,'a',debug=debug)


km = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,12,13,14,15,16]

print p(sum,km*8,debug=True)
```

**Post Updated with some profiling details**

```
    cProfile.run('sum(km*70000000)')
         3 function calls in 15.563 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    8.522    8.522   15.563   15.563 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    7.041    7.041    7.041    7.041 {sum}
```

.

```
    cProfile.run('p(sum,km*70000000)')
         3405 function calls (3383 primitive calls) in 61.501 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1   31.229   31.229   61.501   61.501 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(__getitem__)
        6    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(__getslice__)
        7    0.000    0.000    0.004    0.001 <string>:1(__len__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.001 <string>:1(append)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(pop)
        4    0.001    0.000    0.113    0.028 __init__.py:90(Manager)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.021    0.001 connection.py:161(Client)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:183(Pipe)
       24    0.001    0.000    0.003    0.000 connection.py:297(SocketClient)
       24    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 connection.py:416(deliver_challenge)
       24    0.002    0.000    0.013    0.001 connection.py:429(answer_challenge)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:73(_init_timeout)
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 connection.py:98(address_type)
       17    0.001    0.000    0.062    0.004 forking.py:116(__init__)
       88    0.001    0.000    6.693    0.076 forking.py:131(poll)
       17    0.000    0.000    6.713    0.395 forking.py:152(wait)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 forking.py:168(terminate)
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hmac.py:100(_current)
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hmac.py:109(digest)
       48    0.000    0.000    0.002    0.000 hmac.py:125(new)
       48    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 hmac.py:30(__init__)
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 hmac.py:83(update)
      5/1    0.004    0.001   30.260   30.260 main.py:22(p)
       17   23.375    1.375   23.376    1.375 main.py:7(chunks)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 managers.py:473(__init__)
        4    0.001    0.000    0.111    0.028 managers.py:504(start)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 managers.py:522(<genexpr>)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.010    0.003 managers.py:560(_create)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.023    0.006 managers.py:604(_finalize_manager)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.020    0.005 managers.py:665(temp)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 managers.py:683(__init__)
        4    0.001    0.000    0.006    0.001 managers.py:699(__init__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.001 managers.py:737(_connect)
       16    0.001    0.000    0.005    0.000 managers.py:746(_callmethod)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.001 managers.py:782(_incref)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.003    0.001 managers.py:798(_decref)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 managers.py:80(__init__)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.005    0.000 managers.py:97(dispatch)
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:107(<genexpr>)
       17    0.003    0.000    0.066    0.004 process.py:116(start)
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:133(terminate)
       17    0.001    0.000    6.713    0.395 process.py:139(join)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:149(is_alive)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:161(name)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:165(name)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:185(authkey)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 process.py:59(current_process)
       17    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 process.py:76(_cleanup)
       17    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 process.py:94(__init__)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 socket.py:189(__init__)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 socket.py:196(close)
       72    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 socket.py:227(meth)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:1143(currentThread)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 threading.py:958(name)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.001    0.000 util.py:161(register_after_fork)
        8    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 util.py:176(__init__)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.027    0.003 util.py:192(__call__)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 util.py:347(__init__)
        8    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 util.py:68(sub_debug)
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 util.py:72(debug)
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 util.py:76(info)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:105(__setitem__)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:277(__new__)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:282(__init__)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 weakref.py:55(remove)
       96    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {_hashlib.openssl_md5}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method __new__ of type object at 0x100161d60}
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {chr}
       13    0.006    0.000    0.006    0.000 {eval}
      240    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {getattr}
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
      100    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {hasattr}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {id}
       76    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {isinstance}
  153/135    0.001    0.000    0.005    0.000 {len}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'acquire' of 'thread.lock' objects}
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'add' of 'set' objects}
       13    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
       20    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'close' of '_multiprocessing.Connection' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'connect' of '_socket.socket' objects}
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'copy' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
       96    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'digest' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'discard' of 'set' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'fileno' of '_socket.socket' objects}
       34    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'flush' of 'file' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'get' of 'dict' objects}
       21    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
       44    0.073    0.002    0.073    0.002 {method 'recv' of '_multiprocessing.Connection' objects}
       72    0.011    0.000    0.011    0.000 {method 'recv_bytes' of '_multiprocessing.Connection' objects}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'release' of 'thread.lock' objects}
       40    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'send' of '_multiprocessing.Connection' objects}
       72    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 {method 'send_bytes' of '_multiprocessing.Connection' objects}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'setblocking' of '_socket.socket' objects}
       48    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'startswith' of 'str' objects}
       96    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'translate' of 'str' objects}
      192    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'update' of '_hashlib.HASH' objects}
        9    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {min}
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WEXITSTATUS}
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WIFEXITED}
       17    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.WIFSIGNALED}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.dup}
       17    0.061    0.004    0.061    0.004 {posix.fork}
       75    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.getpid}
        4    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.pipe}
       24    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {posix.urandom}
       84    6.692    0.080    6.692    0.080 {posix.waitpid}
      288    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {setattr}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {thread.get_ident}
        9    0.019    0.002    0.019    0.002 {time.sleep}
       37    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}
```

Comment: You are giving your function a very small input array, the overhead of setting up and initializing the threads is probably a large proportion of the processing time.  Try making your array much larger.

Comment: Your solution includes overheads of some preworks. Benchmark with larger inputs.

Comment: @GWW please check my updated post where I include profiling details with a very large array.

Comment: @Fallen I don't think this is the case because I also tried with a huge array. Check my update on post.